# Computer Vision Three Layer RGB

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, vision

I found this:

```
red = np.uint8([[[0,0,255]]])
hsv_red = cv2.cvtColor(red,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
print(hsv_red)
```

in tutorial openCV Chaning Colospace. I dont understand with `np.uint8([[[0,0,255]]])`. Can you explain why use `[]` three times?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the dimensions:

```
np.uint8([[[0,0,255]]]).shape
# (1, 1, 3)

np.uint8([0,0,255]).shape
# (3,)
```

It makes sense in the context of images since a color image is a matrix of `(n x m x 3)`. Then `(1 x 1 x 3)` is a point.